# How do I restrict column filtering in Kendo UI grid to only allow the 'OR' operator?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In the Kendo UI grid you have the option to set many attributes for the filter UI on each column.   I have a column in a grid defined as follows:

```
{
            field: 'task',
            title: 'Task',
            width: 110,
            filterable: {
                ui: tasksFilter,
                operators: {
                    string: {
                        eq: "Is equal to"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I want the user to have the 2 options that is normally joined by a dropdown where they can select "and" or "or" but "or" is the only valid option.  Is there a parameter in the column definition that will allow me to restrict the user to "or"?